# Dictionary topic in Python

Tags: dictionary, python-3.x

I have one problem of Python Dictionary please give the ans of the que. ASAP

Suppose dlist is a list of dictionaries and k is a key that appears in all the dictionaries in dlist.
Write a comprehension whose value is the list whose ith element is the value corresponding to key k in the
ith dictionary in dlist.
Test your comprehension with some data. Here are some example data.

```
dlist = [{'James':'Sean', 'director':'Terence'}, {'James':'Roger',
'director':'Lewis'}, {'James':'Pierce', 'director':'Roger'}]
k = 'James'
```

So you have to give the ans. ['Sean' , 'Roger' , 'Pierce']

Just write the comprehension of one line.

Thank you for your reply in Advance

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the error messages you're getting now?  If you know how to write a list comprehension, and you know how to get a value from a dictionary given a key, this should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

```
[d[k] for d in dlist]
```

Have you even tried to do it yourself? Did you read about comprehensions?